# MockStatic test a static method that returns an int array

Tags: java, junit, mockito

my function

```
class A {
   public static int[] getArray(String text) { return new int[]{0,3}; }
}
```

test method:

```
private static MockedStatic<A> mock;

@Test
public void Should_return_array_getArray() {
    mock
        .when(() -> A.getArray(text)) // line: 58
        .thenReturn(new int[] {0, 3});
    final int[] values = A.getArray(text);
    System.out.println("value:"+ values[1]);
    assertEquals(3, values[1]);
}
```

Comes up with following error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException at StringTest.java:58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to test.. as your actual method does not take any argument but in testcase you are trying to pass `text` variable...

If you want to test actual method execution, you don't need mocking. Here are example of testing actual invocation of target method and with mocking as well:

```
@Test
public void test_actual_static_method() {
    final int[] values = A.getArray();
    Assertions.assertEquals(3, values[1]);
}

@Test
public void test_mocked_static_method() {
    MockedStatic<A> aMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(A.class);
    aMockedStatic.when(A::getArray).thenReturn(new int[] {100,200});
    Assertions.assertEquals(200, A.getArray()[1]);
}
```

Also you will need `mockito-inline` library

```
@Test
public void test_mocked_static_method_with_args() {
    try(MockedStatic<A> aMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(A.class)) {
        aMockedStatic.when(() -> A.getArrayWithArg("s1")).thenReturn(new int[]{100, 200});
        Assertions.assertEquals(200, A.getArrayWithArg("s1")[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have "mockito-inline" library ... Your second test method with mocking shows =>  error: incompatible types: invalid method reference
                .when(A::getArray)
                          ^
    method getArray in class A cannot be applied to given types
      required: String
      found: no arguments
      reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Looks like you updated signature of `A.getArray()` to `A.getArray(String)`.. if so, please modify test code according

Comment: I fixed my method and changed the test method. I followed your second approach of test method. Would you please check - a new error showing

Comment: couple of modifications needed considering arguments and to avoid impact of mocked changes on other testcases

I have updated answer with another example test method with args

Comment: I am glad I could help ! But I did not follow why are you using `thenCallRealMethod()` to invoke static method. `thenCallRealMethod()` is more helpful when you have a mocked  object with some instance methods mocked for testcase but want actual invocation of instance methodA() then you will use `thenCallRealMethod()` to invoke methodA(). As methodA() is an instance method, you cannot call it directly like static method.

Comment: Your point is right. May be I misunderstood but question is why should we recommend to return my expected values using ".thenReturn(new int[] {100, 200})" - the target method should return actual value by executing actual logic and then assert with expected value. If my concept is wrong please enlighten me please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242123/discussion-between-subhash-and-tajuddin-khandaker).

Comment: Would someone recommend if we mock inside try(){} block do we need to call MockStatic<>::reset()/close() before the block ends?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Subhash ... your suggested solution worked :)
but i called ".thenCallRealMethod()"

```
 @Test
    public void Should_return_truth_getArray() {
        try ( MockedStatic<A> mocked = mockStatic(A.class)) {
            mocked
                .when(() -> A.getArray(text))
                .thenCallRealMethod();
            final int[] values = A.getArray(text);
            System.out.println("value:"+ values[1]);
            assertEquals(3, values[1]);
        }
    }
```